# How can I use add and drop in visual studio 2015 c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, addition

I would like to build an application using C++, but I am facing a problem with the GUI. is there a simple way to make a user interface just by adding and drops buttons and labels like in Java ? Some told me to use QT but I want to use visual studio. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible (using MFC), but generally not advised--direct support in Visual Studio is nearly the *only* remaining strength of MFC.

Comment: Qt is a library which you can use with C++ to develop GUIs.  So yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a Resource Editor, that allows you to drag/drop various controls from the Toolbox panel onto your dialog. You don't really need MFC support for that.

You can use an App Wizard to create new project of a Win32 type, open its .rc file, add new dialog and start experimenting.